# how to delete item in listfield for django nonrel

Tags: python, django, mongodb, listfield

I use mongodb as the django nonrel database to build a blog site. The basic models for the blog site are:

```
  class Post:
      comments = ListField(EmbeddedModelField('Comment'))
      ....(omitted here)

  class Comment:
      created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      author = models.CharField(max_length=35)
      email = models.EmailField(max_length=64)
      text =  models.TextField()
      ip_addr =  models.IPAddressField()
```

I found that when I created a comment and append it to the listfield of a post, the comment will not have an objectid because it's embedded. Thus, when I want to delete a comment, I have trouble to let the database know which comment I want to delete. Is it possible that I pass the comment from the template to views without the url function in urls.py?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the model as

```
class Post:
    comments = ListField(models.ForeignKey('Comment'))
    ....(omitted here)

class Comment:
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=64)
    text =  models.TextField()
    ip_addr =  models.IPAddressField()
```

Comment: Since I use the non-relational database, using foreignkey will sacrifice the speed. I would like to stick with embedded field if possible.